# How can I access the methods of Department class using Student class object

Tags: java, class, object, getter-setter

Create a class Department with the following private member variables

```
int did
String dname
```

Include appropriate getters and setters method in Department class.

Create a class Student with the following private member variables

```
int sid
String sname
Department department
```

Include appropriate getters and setters method in Student class.

Create a TestMain class which has main method.

In addition to main method, create a method

```
       public static Student createStudent() -  All input as shown in the sample input should be got in this method.  Set the values to the Student object and return that object
```

Note : In main method, invoke the createStudent method and print the details of the object returned by that method.

I have already tried creating a new object using the name of Department but I am not able to access the methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {

    public static Student student;
    public static Department department;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        createStudent();
        System.out.println("Department id:" + department.getDid());
        System.out.println("Department name:" + department.getDname());
        System.out.println("Student id:" + student.getSid());
        System.out.println("Student name:" + student.getSname());
    }

    public static Student createStudent() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        student = new Student();
        department = new Department();
        System.out.println("Enter the Department id:");
        department.setDid(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter the Department name:");
        department.setDname(sc.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the Student id:");
        student.setSid(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter the Student name:");
        student.setSname(sc.next());
        return student;
    }
}

public class Student {

    private int sid;
    private String sname;
    private Department department;

    public int getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}

public class Department {

    private int did;
    private String dname;

    public int getDid() {
        return did;
    }

    public void setDid(int did) {
        this.did = did;
    }

    public String getDname() {
        return dname;
    }

    public void setDname(String dname) {
        this.dname = dname;
    }
}
```

Sample Input 1:

```
Enter the Department id:
100
Enter the Department name:
Computerscience

Enter the Student id:
123
Enter the Student name:
Sudha
```

Sample Output 1:

```
Department id:100
Department name:Computerscience
Student id:123
Student name:sudha
```

Comment: If you are getting an error message, please post it (and point out which line(s) it refers to, as we can't necessarily tell what the line numbers are).

Comment: *In main method, invoke the createStudent method and print the details of the object returned by that method.*: Since you do not save the object returned by this method, you cannot print anything about it.  Note: it is a Student, not a Department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing:

```
student.setDepartment(department);
```

after that, you can do:

```
student.getDepartment().getSname();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestMain
{
    public static Department d1;
    public static Student s1;
    public static Student createStudent()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Student s1=new Student();
        Department d1=new Department();
        System.out.println("Enter the Department id:");
        int did=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Department name:");
        String dname=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Student id:");
        int sid=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Student name:");
        String sname=sc.nextLine();
        d1.setDid(did);
        d1.setDname(dname);
        s1.setSid(sid);
        s1.setSname(sname);
        s1.setDepartment(d1);
        return s1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        s1=TestMain.createStudent();
        System.out.println("Department id:"+d1.getDid());
        System.out.println("Department name:"+d1.getDname());
        System.out.println("Student id:"+s1.getSid());
        System.out.println("Student name:"+s1.getSname());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
 s1 =  createStudent();
 d1 = s1.getDepartment(); // THIS WAS MISSING IN ANSWER 2
 System.out.println("Department id:"+d1.getDid());
 System.out.println("Department name:"+d1.getDname());
 System.out.println("Student id:"+s1.getSid());
 System.out.println("Student name:"+s1.getSname());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there are 2 things that must be done.

1. While "setting" values for all the ids and names, after the did and dname had been set, in order to access that via student object, you must "set" the did & dname combo to the department object inside student class.

   ```
   department.setDid(did);
   department.setDname(dname);
   student.setSid(sid);
   student.setSname(sname);
   student.setDepartment(department);
   ```
2. Also, now once this is set with right values, before the Sysout statements in Main, you  have to create an object for the Department class. And the data for this comes by calling the `getDepartment()` in student class (Remember that this function returns a Department object).

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Student student = createStudent();
       Department department = student.getDepartment();
       System.out.printf("Department id:%d",department.getDid()).println();
       System.out.printf("Department name:%s",department.getDname()).println();
       System.out.printf("Student id:%d",student.getSid()).println();
       System.out.printf("Student name:%s",student.getSname()).println();
   }
   ```